# console.log() not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, logging, console

console.log() doesn't work in Chrome latest stable build. I'm using Kendo UI Mobile and want to log some stuff. alert() apparently works when used instead of console.log().

Chrome Version 27.0.1453.110 m

Comment: Can you add the exact version number to the question? Today's "latest build" is not the same as next year's "latest build". Also, please check if `console.log` is disabled by a JavaScript library, or if it's completely disabled in Chrome (via devtools).

Comment: The questions is already answered by me. I posted it to help others facing the same issue.

Comment: I saw, and tried to reproduce it. console.log is defined regardless of the "Emulate touch" setting. That causes me to believe that the cause of your issue lies in a JavaScript library.

Answer (score 1):

Using "Emulate Touch Events" option from Chrome's Dev tools will prevent console.log() from writing logs to the console.